# How does a phase shifter for an electron beam work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

It is well known that if we insert a phase shifter behind one of the slits in a double slit experiment, the interference pattern gets altered.

In mathematical terms this follows because only one contribution $\psi_2$  to the total wave function $\psi = \psi_1 + \psi_2$ gets shifted:
$$ \psi =  \psi_1 + e^{i\varphi} \psi_2 \to \psi' =  \psi_1 + e^{i\varphi} \psi_2 $$

**How can we achieve, in a real world experiment, that the wave function that describes, say, an electron beam gets shifted?** And, in particular, what determines the amount by which the phase is modified $\varphi$?

Comment: There is the [Aharonov–Bohm effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect#Magnetic_solenoid_effect).

Comment: @KeithMcClary yes. But there also seems to be phase shifters for electrons that seem to work like those for electromagnetic waves. My question is inspired by the discussion in Gauge Theories of the Forces between Elementary Particles by tHooft. https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/gauge-theories-of-the-forces-betwee/

Comment: @KeithMcClary he specifically compares the influence of a phase shifter with the effect caused by an aharonov-bohm type setup.

Comment: I found a non-paywalled [source](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/4662). Where in the article?

Comment: @KeithMcClary the second figure one page 99 titled "Local Gauge Symmetry"

Comment: I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_optics#Diffractive_electron_optics) in Wikipedia.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Thanks a lot!